# How to give a warning and ask for raw_input again - while inside a loop

Tags: python

I have written the Python code below (actually it's my solution for an exercise from page 80 of "Teach yourself Python in 24 hours").

The idea is: there are 4 seats around the table, the waiter knows for how much each seat ordered, enters those 4 amounts and gets a total.

If the raw_input provided is not a number (but a string) my code kicks the person out. The goal, however, is to give an error message ("this entry is not valid") and ask for the input again - until it's numeric. However, I can't figure out how to ask the user for the raw input again - because I am already inside a loop.

Thanks a lot for your advice!

```
def is_numeric(value):
  try:
    input = float(value)
  except ValueError:
    return False
  else:
    return True


total = 0
for seat in range(1,5):

  print 'Note the amount for seat', seat, 'and'
  myinput = raw_input("enter it here ['q' to quit]: ")

  if myinput == 'q':
    break

  elif is_numeric(myinput):
    floatinput = float(myinput)
    total = total + floatinput

  else:
    print 'I\'m sorry, but {} isn\'t valid. Please try again'.format(myinput)
    break

if myinput == 'q':
  print "Goodbye!"
else:
  total = round(total, 2)
  print "*****\nTotal: ${}".format(total)
  print "Goodbye!"
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when you don't know how many times you want to run your loop the solution is a `while` loop.

```
for seat in range(1,5):
   my_input = raw_input("Enter: ")
   while not(my_input == 'q' or isnumeric(my_input)):
        my_input = raw_imput("Please re-enter value")
   if my_input == 'q':
        break
   else:
       total += float(my_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0
for seat in range(1,5):
    incorrectInput = True
    while(incorrectInput):
        print 'Note the amount for seat', seat, 'and'
        myinput = raw_input("enter it here ['q' to quit]: ")

        if myinput == 'q':
            print 'Goodbye'
            quit()

        elif is_numeric(myinput):
            floatinput = float(myinput)
            total = total + floatinput
            incorrectInput = False

        else:
            print 'I\'m sorry, but {} isn\'t valid. Please try again'.format(myinput)


total = round(total, 2)
print "*****\nTotal: ${}".format(total)
print "Goodbye!"
```

Comment: This (2nd) solution is not exactly working (btw, one typo False, not false). If it's built this way then when I enter a wrong amount (a string), then it still moves over to the 2nd seat and considers the amount for the previous seat as 0.

Comment: Sorry, I left the break in the else statement. A good lesson for me to always test the code with an interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick Haugh and SilentLupin suggested, a `while` loop is probably the best way. Another way is recursion- ie, calling the same function over and over until you get a valid input:

```
def is_numeric(value):
  try:
    input = float(value)
  except ValueError:
    return False
  else:
    return True

def is_q(value):
  return value ==  'q'

def is_valid(value, validators):
  return any(validator(input) for validator in validators) 

def get_valid_input(msg, validators):
  value = raw_input(msg)
  if not is_valid(value, validators):
    print 'I\'m sorry, but {} isn\'t valid. Please try again'.format(value)
    value = get_valid_input(msg, validators)
  return value

total = 0
for seat in range(1,5):

  print 'Note the amount for seat', seat, 'and'
  myinput = get_valid_input("enter it here ['q' to quit]: ", [is_q, is_numeric])

  if myinput == 'q':
    break

  elif is_numeric(myinput):
    floatinput = float(myinput)
    total = total + floatinput

if myinput == 'q':
  print "Goodbye!"
else:
  total = round(total, 2)
  print "*****\nTotal: ${}".format(total)
  print "Goodbye!"
```

In the above code, `get_valid_input` calls itself over and over again until one of the supplied `validators` produces something truthy.